# Tensorflow image detection, ImportError: Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140_1.dll'

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror

I am trying to follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqkISICHH-U) but I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Tensorflow-object-detection\TFODCourse\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
  File "C:\Tensorflow-object-detection\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Tensorflow-object-detection\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Tensorflow-object-detection\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 26, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Tensorflow-object-detection\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 50, in preload_check
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140_1.dll'. TensorFlow requires that these DLLs be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. You may install these DLLs by downloading "Microsoft C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" for your platform from this URL: https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
```

I guess it was due to the absence of the 'msvcp140_1.dll' file. However, the 'msvcp140_1.dll' file is in my `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` path; I don't know what the reason is. So, I went to [this address](https://www.microsoft.com/ko-kr/download/details.aspx?id=48145), downloaded it and rebooted my pc, but the problem still exists. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Add the directory which you found the `dll` on to the PATH variable under environment variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like issue with MS Visual studio.
You need download and install visual studio 2015-2019 x86 and x64 from here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads.

You need to check, does your CPU support AVX2 instructions or not.